# Check if webpage exists using Java

Tags: java, web, connection, httpurlconnection

I'm using Java to check the response of a url I pass in. This is the current code I'm using. However, I keep getting a connection refused error. I'm testing with the basic Google home page so that I know the rough draft of my code works.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class connectTest {


public static void main(String[] args)
{

    boolean test = pageExists();

}
public static boolean pageExists(){

        int returnCode= 0;

       try {
             HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
             String httpsURL = "https://www.google.com/";
             URL testUrl = new URL(httpsURL);
             HttpsURLConnection con = 
             (HttpsURLConnection)testUrl.openConnection();

             returnCode= con.getResponseCode();
             System.out.println(returnCode);


       } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       }

       if (returnCode== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
           return true;
       }
       else if (returnCode== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST || returnCode== 
        HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND ){
           return false;
       }
       else 
       {
           System.out.println("The return code was not 200,400 or 404");
           return false;

       }


    }  
  }
```

This is the error I get when I run the following:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you trying this behind a proxy?

Comment: yes, I am. Is that the problem?

Comment: If you want to check if a domain is already taken, you can't do it this way

Comment: What exactly is your real goal here?

Comment: Before making the http call set the below to pass through proxy. This would be your network credentials.

System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", authUser);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", authPassword);